# Why do non-Apple earbuds make my iPhone act erratically?

Tags: iphone, microphone, ear-phones

I have tried a couple of different brands of earbuds supposedly compatible with the iPhone, but on both, the mic doesn't seem to work and the phone itself will make Siri pop up, shut down or advance the audiobook I'm reading?

I've read the other earbud questions and the two non-Apple connectors have four sections, but the ends are straighter/not angled as the iphone ones.

Comment: Do you have a question here or are you just making a comment?  If you have a question, please reformat what you're saying to include your question.

Comment: I had that problem too, best thing I ever did tho was plantronics Bluetooth backbeat go earbuds (you'll have to google them--the benefits of earbuds with a wire between, but wireless to the phone) while a little more expensive and adds another item to charge---they are the most excellent earbuds I've ever had, both for music/video and phone calls.  Also worth noting I've heard rumors the audio jack may likely vanish in a future iPhone apparently it's component right now is part of the thickness factor.